# Wordpress Add custom post types with custom taxonomy to custom admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-admin

I've created multiple custom post types and the backend menu is getting messy because i have like 20 post types.

I wanted to put all of my posttypes under a admin menu item (called "Alle post types"), I got this working but I only get the option for "All [Custom Post Type]"

[image]

I would like to have the menu item "Recepten" with the taximonies and the "add Recept" buttons like if you set "show_in_menu" to true.

[image]

The code for creating the custom post type "Recepten" is this

```
function recepten_post_type()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x('Recepten', 'Post Type General Name', 'jointswp'),
        'singular_name'         => _x('Recept', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'jointswp'),
        'menu_name'             => __('Recepten', 'jointswp'),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __('Recepten', 'jointswp'),
        'archives'              => __('Recepten bibliotheek', 'jointswp'),
        'attributes'            => __('Recept Attributen', 'jointswp'),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent Item:', 'jointswp'),
        'all_items'             => __('Alle Recepten', 'jointswp'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Voeg Recept toe', 'jointswp'),
        'add_new'               => __('Add New', 'jointswp'),
        'new_item'              => __('Nieuwe Recept', 'jointswp'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Bewerk Recept', 'jointswp'),
        'update_item'           => __('Update Recept', 'jointswp'),
        'view_item'             => __('Bekijk Recept', 'jointswp'),
        'view_items'            => __('Bekijk Recepten', 'jointswp'),
        'search_items'          => __('Zoek Recept', 'jointswp'),
        'not_found'             => __('Not found', 'jointswp'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Not found in Trash', 'jointswp'),
        'featured_image'        => __('Featured Image', 'jointswp'),
        'set_featured_image'    => __('Set featured image', 'jointswp'),
        'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove featured image', 'jointswp'),
        'use_featured_image'    => __('Use as featured image', 'jointswp'),
        'insert_into_item'      => __('Voeg toe aan Recept', 'jointswp'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this item', 'jointswp'),
        'items_list'            => __('Items list', 'jointswp'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Items list navigation', 'jointswp'),
        'filter_items_list'     => __('Filter items list', 'jointswp'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __('Recepten', 'jointswp'),
        'description'           => __('Recepten Verstege', 'jointswp'),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => 'post-types',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 11,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'rewrite'     => array(
            'slug'       => 'recepten',
        )
    );
    register_post_type('recept', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'recepten_post_type', 0);
```

And how i create my custom taximony is like this

```
function create_recipe_custom_taxonomy()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Recept Filter', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Filter', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' =>  __('Zoek filter'),
        'all_items' => __('Alle Filters'),
        'parent_item' => __('HoofdFilter'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('HoofdFilter:'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Filter'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Filter'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Nieuwe Filter'),
        'new_item_name' => __('Nieuwe Filter'),
        'menu_name' => __('Filters'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('recipe-filters', array('recept'), array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            =>  $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => 'post-types',
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'filter'),
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'create_recipe_custom_taxonomy', 1);
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: `remove_submenu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()` could be a manual way of doing it, else there are plugins which can do the same

Comment: like this : https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Comment: That might work but I rather have it automaticly. And I think this should be possible right?

Comment: Thing is, You can not have sub menus of sub menus - but you can add the links for new, taxonomies etc after the post type all, you might need some CSS after that though, because it seems messy

Comment: Oh you can't? that sucks well thank you for your help!